# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Failed manual deployment of .war file in WebSphere 8.5

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am using worklight 6.0 and websphere 8.5.
While deploying the worklight war, im getting the following error.

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'brokerSessionFactory' defined in URL
 [wsjar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]:
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
 javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    ... 116 more

 Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
 javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.toOpenJPAProperties(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:477)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation.load(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:315)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:160)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:62)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:224)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 126 more
```

Comment: What steps did you follow in order to deploy Worklight? Did you use the Ant task script or manual work?

Comment: Iam deploying manually.I have followed the steps given under this.http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdeploy%2Fc_deploy_custom_war_file_to_app_server.html

Comment: Hey Idan, I solved the issue by setting the classloader order as Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last).Anyways thanks Idan.

Answer (score 2):

In typical fashion, the user asked a question and disappeared...

The solution, as written in the comments:

> I solved the issue by setting the classloader order as
>   "Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)".

More information about this setting can be read [in this IBM WebSphere Information Center topic](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/urun_rclassloader_inst.html).